# Form validation on blur

Tags: javascript, dom, onblur

I have 5 input fields and I want them to validate on blur, and show either an error or success message, but through DOM scripting and not with an alert box. I've tried several different codes, even just small bits and pieces to see if it's correctly interacting with my html but it doesn't seem to work.
So far, I have a small code to test if it even runs, and it's supposed to show an alert box but it does not. I would prefer to not use any innerHTML and use all functions within the javascript only. 
My html:

```
<div id=fNID>
                <label for="firstNameID">First Name: </label>
                <input id="firstNameID" type="text" name="firstNameA" value="" />
                <span> </span>
            </div>

            <div id=lNID>
                <label for="lastNameID">Last Name: </label>
                <input id="lastNameID" type="text" name="lastNameA" value="" />
                <span> </span>
            </div>
```

My javascript:

```
    firstNameID = document.surveyForm.getElementById("firstNameID");
    document.surveyForm.getElementById(fN).addEventListener("blur", validateName);
    function validateName() {
        var nameRegEx = /[a-zA-Z]+/;
        var firstNameID = document.getElementById("firstNameID");

        if (fN.matches(nameRegEx)) {
            alert("Success!")
        } else {
            alert("error")
        }
    }


    window.addEventListener("load", setupForm, false);
}
```

Comment: Where would you show success/error messages if you dont want to use `innerHTML`?

Comment: I was hoping to show them directly next to the input field. This is my first coding project so I'm sorry if things don't make sense!

Comment: Your logic is correct, you would just need to set innerHTML for the span tags next to inputs, you can find out how to do that from many online resources

Comment: I'm not allowed to use innerhtml for this class unfortunately. I think the main problem for me is trying to figure out how to do it a different way. Thank you though!

Comment: Well there's innerText, textContent..its strange that something would not be allowed

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a nice pattern for [input validation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/#validation). They use divs following the input: one for valid input, one for invalid input, making the appropriate one visible:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="uname">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap's CSS classes modify the display based on the input's pseudo-classes `:valid` and `:invalid`.

You can set these pseudo-classes in JavaScript with the setCustomValidity() method.

```
input.setCustomValidity("input is invalid")
```

will assign the `:invalid` pseudo-class to the input.

```
input.setCustomValidity("")
```

will assign the `:valid` pseudo class.

A working example:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('uname');

function makeValid() {
  input.setCustomValidity('');
}

function makeInvalid() {
  input.setCustomValidity('a problem');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="m-2">Bootstrap input with validation</h3>
<form class="was-validated mx-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="uname">Username (required):</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname">
    <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">This field is invalid.</div>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="m-2">
  <p>Use setCustomValidity() to change input state:</p>
  <button onclick="makeValid();">:valid</button>
  <button onclick="makeInvalid();">:invalid</button>
</div>
```

It's also worth noting that most browsers have native support for displaying validation messages on inputs. Here's an example that doesn't use any Bootstrap features:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('uname');

function makeValid() {
  input.setCustomValidity('');
}

function makeInvalid() {
  input.setCustomValidity('this is invalid');
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.m-2 {
  margin: .5rem;
}

.mt-5 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3 class="m-2">Generic input with validation</h3>
  <form class="mt-5">
    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname">
    <p>Use setCustomValidity() to change input state:</p>

    <button onclick="makeInvalid();">input:invalid</button>
  </form>
  <div class="m-2">
    <button onclick="makeValid();">input:valid</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! I think i can incorporate this idea into what I'm working on. My professor also prohibits the use of external libraries so it's been tricky trying to figure it out

Comment: The built-in `input.setCustomValidity(message)` function is useful, too. Call it with any message to mark an input invalid, use `message = ''` (empty string) to mark it valid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity